# Is that proof right? (If $F \subset R^n$ is a closed set and $A \subset R^n$ is an open set, then $F \setminus A$ is a closed set)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

From $F$ is closed we have:

$\forall x \in F, \forall \epsilon >0, \exists y \in B_\epsilon(x) \cap F$

From $A$ is open, we can show that $A^c$ is closed:

---

We have that

$\forall x \in A, \exists \epsilon > 0, B_\epsilon(x) \subset A$

We will prove that $\bar A^c \subset A^c$

$\bar A^c := \{x|(x_n)_{n\in N}\subset A^c, x_n \rightarrow x\}$

By contradiction, suppose we have one $\bar x$ such that $\bar x \in \bar A^c$ but $\bar x \notin A^c$.

From $\bar x \in A$, we have: $\exists \delta > 0 B_\delta(\bar x) \subset A$.

From $x_n \rightarrow x$, we have that $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists n_0 \in N; n > n_o \implies d(x_n,\bar x) < \epsilon$. In particular for $\epsilon = \delta$, we can get one $x_n \in B_\delta(\bar x)$. But it's a contradiction because $B_\delta \subset A$ and $(x_n)_{n \in N} \subset A^c$.

So we can conclude that $\bar A^c \subset A^c$, it is, A^c is a closed set.

---

From $A^c$ is closed, then:

$\forall x \in A^c, \forall \epsilon >0, \exists y \in B_\epsilon(x) \cap A^c$

So, $x \in F\setminus A = F \cap A^c \implies (\forall \epsilon >0, \exists y \in B_\epsilon(x) \cap F) \wedge (\forall \epsilon >0, \exists y \in B_\epsilon(x) \cap A^c)$

It is:

$x \in F\setminus A \implies \forall \epsilon >0, (\exists y \in B_\epsilon(x) \cap F) \wedge (\exists y \in B_\epsilon(x) \cap A^c)$

And then we have:

$\forall x \in F\setminus A, \forall \epsilon > 0 , \exists y \in B_e(x)\cap(F\setminus A)$

We can conclude that $F\setminus A$ is closed.

I'm still learning about how to make proofs, so any comment about the form of the proof will also be very helpfull! Thanks!

Comment: Or simply, $F\setminus A=F\cap\complement A$, which is the intersection of two closed sets

Comment: @AnthonySaint-Criq Yes! I will edit it... it's a typo heheh

Comment: What I meant is that it is known that 1) intersection of closed sets is closed, and 2) complements of open sets are closed, so the proof simply boils down to $F\setminus A=F\cap\complement A$ !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the trivial remark that $A^\complement$ is closed when $A$ is open and so $F\setminus A = F \cap A^\complement$ is closed as the intersection of closed sets we can also reason more directly:

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $F\setminus A$ that converges to $x$, and we want to show $x \in F\setminus A$. First note the sequence lies in $F$ in particular, so that $x \in F$ as $F$ is assumed to be closed. Even $x \in F\setminus A$ because if this were *not* the case, knowing $x \in F$, we must then have $x \in A$. But then for some $\varepsilon>0$, $B_\varepsilon(x) \subseteq A$ and for some $N$ we have that for all $n \ge N$ we have $d(x_n, x) < \varepsilon$, by convergence. In particular $x_N \in B_\varepsilon(x)$ so $x_N \in A$ contradicting that the sequence was chosen from $F\setminus A$. So $x \in A$ cannot happen, and so $x \in F\setminus A$ as required.